# "import"ing d3 and d3-cloud with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, ecmascript-6, word-cloud

So, I have been trying to import [d3](https://d3js.org/) and [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud)(for word cloud)
into my AngularJs(v - 1.4) app. I am doing this by - 

*import d3 from 'd3'* 
*import d3Cloud from 'd3-cloud'*.
When I try to use to d3-cloud like **d3.layout.cloud()** I get the following error 
 
*_d2.default.layout.cloud is not a function*

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

//  import and assign libs  **
    import d3 from 'd3' 
    import * as cloud from 'd3-cloud'


@Component({
  selector: 'word-cloud',
  templateUrl: './word-cloud.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./word-cloud.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})

export class WordCloudComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor() { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {

    d3.scale.category20();
    let layout = cloud()
       .size([ width   ,  height   ])
      .words(data)
      .rotate(function () ...)
      .spiral('rectangular')
      .fontSize(function () ...)
      .on("end", function () ...)
      .start();

}
```

Comment: This question is for AngularJS which is not the same as Angular2+ which your solution focuses on.