# Typings for d3-cloud

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, d3-cloud

I want to use [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) to generate a word cloud in my Angular2 app. However, I'm not able to find the right typings to install. I tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3.cloud.layout) but when I tried to import it in my component, it did not work. I kept getting the error, "Property layout could not be found in type". Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? have exactly the same issue at the minute

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I did get it to work. Posted an answer below. Comment if you need more clarifications.

Comment: check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355842/importing-d3-and-d3-cloud-with-webpack/50975582#50975582](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355842/importing-d3-and-d3-cloud-with-webpack/50975582#50975582)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Not the correct Typescript way, but using the fallback JS way. Here's how you'd go about it:

1. `import` the d3 library like usual, but give it an alias: `import * as D3 from 'd3';` (Notice: Capital D for D3)
2. `declare` d3 again so you can use it for WordCloud: `declare let d3: any;`
3. Use `D3` for everything concerning the parent d3 library and `d3` for word cloud generation alone.

The typings for d3-cloud doesn't seem to work. So `declare`ing seems to be the only way for now.

**Full Code**:

**word-cloud.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, DoCheck, KeyValueDiffers } from '@angular/core';
import { WordCloudConfig } from '../../../models/charts/word-cloud-config';
import * as D3 from 'd3';

declare let d3: any;

@Component({
  selector   : 'word-cloud',
  templateUrl: './word-cloud.component.html',
  styleUrls  : ['./word-cloud.component.scss']
})
export class WordCloudComponent implements DoCheck {

  @Input() config: WordCloudConfig;

  private _host;              // D3 object referencing host DOM object
  private _svg;               // SVG in which we will print our chart
  private _margin: {          // Space between the svg borders and the actual chart graphic
    top: number,
    right: number,
    bottom: number,
    left: number
  };
  private _width: number;      // Component width
  private _height: number;     // Component height
  private _htmlElement: HTMLElement; // Host HTMLElement
  private _minCount: number;   // Minimum word count
  private _maxCount: number;   // Maximum word count
  private _fontScale;          // D3 scale for font size
  private _fillScale;          // D3 scale for text color
  private _objDiffer;

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _keyValueDiffers: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this._htmlElement = this._element.nativeElement;
    this._host = D3.select(this._element.nativeElement);
    this._objDiffer = this._keyValueDiffers.find([]).create(null);
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    let changes = this._objDiffer.diff(this.config);
    if (changes) {
      if (!this.config) {
        return;
      }
      this._setup();
      this._buildSVG();
      this._populate();
    }
  }

  private _setup() {
    this._margin = {
      top   : 10,
      right : 10,
      bottom: 10,
      left  : 10
    };
    this._width = ((this._htmlElement.parentElement.clientWidth == 0)
        ? 300
        : this._htmlElement.parentElement.clientWidth) - this._margin.left - this._margin.right;
    if (this._width < 100) {
      this._width = 100;
    }
    this._height = this._width * 0.75 - this._margin.top - this._margin.bottom;

    this._minCount = D3.min(this.config.dataset, d => d.count);
    this._maxCount = D3.max(this.config.dataset, d => d.count);

    let minFontSize: number = (this.config.settings.minFontSize == null) ? 18 : this.config.settings.minFontSize;
    let maxFontSize: number = (this.config.settings.maxFontSize == null) ? 96 : this.config.settings.maxFontSize;
    this._fontScale = D3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([this._minCount, this._maxCount])
                        .range([minFontSize, maxFontSize]);
    this._fillScale = D3.scaleOrdinal(D3.schemeCategory20);
  }

  private _buildSVG() {
    this._host.html('');
    this._svg = this._host
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', this._width + this._margin.left + this._margin.right)
                    .attr('height', this._height + this._margin.top + this._margin.bottom)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ~~(this._width / 2) + ',' + ~~(this._height / 2) + ')');
  }

  private _populate() {
    let fontFace: string = (this.config.settings.fontFace == null) ? 'Roboto' : this.config.settings.fontFace;
    let fontWeight: string = (this.config.settings.fontWeight == null) ? 'normal' : this.config.settings.fontWeight;
    let spiralType: string = (this.config.settings.spiral == null) ? 'rectangular' : this.config.settings.spiral;

    d3.layout.cloud()
      .size([this._width, this._height])
      .words(this.config.dataset)
      .rotate(() => 0)
      .font(fontFace)
      .fontWeight(fontWeight)
      .fontSize(d => this._fontScale(d.count))
      .spiral(spiralType)
      .on('end', () => {
        this._drawWordCloud(this.config.dataset);
      })
      .start();
  }

  private _drawWordCloud(words) {
    this._svg
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(words)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style('font-size', d => d.size + 'px')
        .style('fill', (d, i) => {
          return this._fillScale(i);
        })
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')rotate(' + d.rotate + ')')
        .attr('class', 'word-cloud')
        .text(d => {
          return d.word;
        });
  }

}
```

**word-cloud.component.html**:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**word-cloud.component.scss**:

```
.word-cloud {
  cursor                : default;
  -webkit-touch-callout : none;
  -webkit-user-select   : none;
  -khtml-user-select    : none;
  -moz-user-select      : none;
  -ms-user-select       : none;
  user-select           : none;
}
```

Comment: thanks man, thats working for me now. Just need to play around with the library to get the look I want.

Comment: how did you include d3-cloud in your application? I'm using the angular-cli with webpack, which chokes because the d3-cloud NPM module uses 'require.'

Comment: @ansorensen You need not have to "include" d3-cloud. I simply added `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/v1.2.1/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>` into `index.html` and accessed it using the method mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That link is broken, but the current package does have a build folder. I had been using the index.js (which requires node or browserify) and hadn't realized the build version is standalone.  Just added the build version to my list of compiled scripts, and voila! (Well, plus a lot of massaging the example code from the package).

Comment: Cool! I didn't realize the link was broken all this time. Thanks to you, I fixed it. :D

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS Can you please put also your HTML and CSS?

Comment: @mohammad Updated answer :)

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS What packages should I install using npm?

Comment: @mohammad Just `d3`. You can add `d3-cloud` as described in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763075/typings-for-d3-cloud/42001600?noredirect=1#comment77295431_42001600

Comment: @mohammad I do not understand. Do you mean the `dataset`? If yes, it should be `{ word: string, count: number }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167085/discussion-between-mohammad-and-rajshri-mohan-k-s).

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS Thanks for this, but where is **"WordCloudConfig"**? Or setting?

Comment: What happend? 
I got this error: **"d3 is not defined"**, although I using **declare let d3**

Comment: @MohammadHosseinGanjyar`WordCloudConfig` is my custom class which provides some properties for the example I provided. You should be able to do the same with any class/property of your own.

Answer (score 3):

I worked it out by following below steps -

1. Import d3-cloud npm package --> npm i d3-cloud
2. Import typings of d3-cloud --> npm i @types/d3-cloud --save-dev
3. Now below in the sample component.ts imports and code -

---

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3Cloud from "d3-cloud";

wordCloud(): void {
    let svg: any = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", 850)
        .attr("height", 350);
    d3Cloud().size([800, 300])
        .words(wordList)
}
```