# 'd3 and 'd3-hexbin' in typescript as global libraries

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

So, I'm using `d3` and `d3-hexbin` as global libraries:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
```

... and referencing them in `.ts` as:

```
/// <reference types="d3" />
/// <reference types="d3-hexbin" />
```

... using [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) definitions. However, although this works:

```
const svg = d3.select('#hitmap').append('svg')
```

... this:

```
const hexbin = d3.hexbin().radius(binsize + 1)
```

... fails with a :

```
Property 'hexbin' does not exist on type 
  'typeof "/Users/bytter/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have typings for d3, you don't have the derived typings for d3-hexbin. So you've to fall back to the `declare` method like I did here for d3-cloud: [Typings for d3-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763075/typings-for-d3-cloud)

Basically, the steps you've to follow are these:

1. `import` the d3 library like usual, but give it an alias: `import * as D3 from 'd3';` (Notice: Capital D for D3)
2. `declare` d3 again so you can use it for hexbin: `declare let d3: any;`
3. Use `D3` for everything concerning the parent d3 library and `d3` for hexbin generation alone.

`const svg = D3.select('#hitmap').append('svg');`

`const hexbin = d3.hexbin().radius(binsize + 1);`

This will prevent the editor from showing hexbin specific suggestions and Typescript will not be able to catch hexbin specific type errors. But unfortunately, till official typings arrive for hexbin, this is the best way I've found.