# Can't implement d3-cloud on Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, angular6, d3-cloud

I have problems to implement [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) on an Angular 6 project, basically the same problem that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763075/typings-for-d3-cloud/). I tried [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001600/4504922) there but I doesn't work for me. I can't comment in that topic, so I made this one.

I have multiple errors with that code:

`import { WordCloudConfig } from '../../../models/charts/word-cloud-config'` I don't have this class, and have no idea how its works.

and errors like this:

`Error:(71, 26) TS2339: Property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.`

I appreciated any help. Maybe another solution? Thanks in regards